# Domain Level Cookies in an Akamai setup

Tags: akamai

Has anyone had a problem in running domain level cookies with Akamai implementation?
The site issues a domain level cookie which contains 2 values which are used by other apps.
With Akamai in the mix, the cookie never gets generated. When I take Akamai out of the mix, everything works fine. Not sure if anyone else has seen this behavior. I am not clear on how Akamai handles cookies.

Answer (score 6):

Akamai, by default, strips cookies from cached resources.
The logic (quit sensibly) is that cookies are designed to be specific to each browser/user, so caching them makes no sense.

My advice:
1. Check if the resource in question is being cached. You can use the Akamai browser plugins for this
2. Think carefully why you would want cookies in a cached resource
3. If you are sure you do want these cookies, contact Akamai. They can change this behaviour for you

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you can still cache those pages: you'd need to define the cookies in an uncached URL, which should be called inside the cached pages, for example, as a  tag.

That way you can do redirects, AJAX calls, or DOM manipulation from JS depending on cookies from within cached pages.